# Public URL with Fog and Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Versions of all RubyGems. I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2, [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki) 0.5.8, and [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) 1.1.2.

I am using the CarrierWave RubyGem too for image uploading and the Fog RubyGem for [Amazon S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) file upload.

In my CarrierWave initializer file I have:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: 'xxx',
    aws_secret_access_key: 'xxx'
  }
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_directory = 'bucket1'
  elsif Rails.env.development?
    config.fog_directory = 'bucket2'
  else
    config.fog_directory = 'bucket3'
  end

  config.fog_public = false
  config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 60
end
```

I have an uploader file:

```
class PageAttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
   if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_public = true
   end
  end

 storage :fog
end
```

I am having two uploader files. I want one to be set to private and one to public.

I am trying to overwrite CarrierWave configuarations when PageAttachmentUploader is invoked and set the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to public. This works like charm in the local machine, but it does not work in staging, sandbox and production.

I changed config.fog_public = true in the CarrierWave intializer. Even that does not work in sandbox. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 24):

No, you should not use CarrierWave.configure directly in your uploaders as it will change the default configuration for all uploaders and not only each uploader.

I don't know if that's the best solution but you can change the default fog configuration directly by setting class methods in your uploaders like this :

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog

  def self.fog_public
    true # or false
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, thats correct! fog_public :true in uploader file worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the best way (I've found) is to do the following:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog

  configure do |c|
    c.fog_public = true # or false
  end
end
```

It feels more in line with CarrierWave's style to do it this way.